# Another definition in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $g$ be an arbitrary inner product on $\mathbb R^n$. My question is whether the trace of a real matrix $[a_{ij}]_{n\times n}$ could be written as $$\sum_{i=1}^ng([a_{ij}]f_i,f_i)$$ for an orthonormal basis $\{f_i\}_{i=1}^n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with inner product $g$, i.e. $g(f_i,f_i)=1$, $g(f_i,f_j)=0$ for $i\neq j$. In other words, is it true that
$$\sum_{i=1}^na_{ii}=\sum_{i=1}^n\langle[a_{ij}]e_i,e_i\rangle\stackrel{??}=\sum_{i=1}^ng([a_{ij}]f_i,f_i)$$
where $\langle \;,\;\rangle$ is standard inner product on $\mathbb R^n$ and $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$ ?

Comment: I guess my trouble with the question is that when I think of a matrix I connect it to a linear transformation. So, the better question in my estimation would be, is the trace defined for a linear transformation. The answer to that is yes. Why, because the trace is invariant under a similarity transformation.... I must think more on your question...

Comment: @James S. Cook: The second sentence of this post is a question, and so is the last sentence though it does not end with a question mark.

Comment: Where you have $[a_{ij}]f_i$, do you mean $\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}f_j$, or something like that?

Comment: @AlanU.Kennington that's meant to denote multiplying the matrix $[a_{ij}]$ by the vector $f_i$.

Comment: @PVanchinathan fair enough. I think the given answer does justice to the question asked. But, I still think that we should think of transformations as primary objects... not matrices.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook I tried to keep things as matrix-agnostic as possible while working within the framework of the question.  If you define trace with respect to an inner product and choice of orthonormal basis, it's natural to ask whether the result is invariant over one's choice of inner product and basis, and it's convenient to think of this in terms of matrices.  I wonder if this proof can be made nicer using, for example, the fact that the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues, which causes us to ignore the inner product altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes.  One possible proof is as follows:

Begin by noting that any inner product can be expressed in the form
$$
(x,y) = y^TBx
$$
for some (symmetric) positive definite matrix $B$.  Let us choose such an $B$.  Let $A = [a_{ij}]$ denote the matrix of our transformation. We then have $f_j^T B f_i  = \delta_{ij}$.

Let $M$ denote the matrix whose $i$th column is $f_i$ so that $f_i = M e_i$.  We can rewrite our statement about the $f_i$ as $e_j^TM^TBMe_i = \delta_{ij}$, so that $M^TBM = I$.  Because $M$ is invertible, we can rewrite this further to give us
$$
M^TB = M^{-1} \implies MM^TB = I \implies MM^T = B^{-1}
$$
We may now compute
$$
\sum_{i} (A f_i, f_i) = \sum_{i} f_i^T ABf_i = 
\sum_{i} e_i^T M^TABMe_i = \\
\operatorname{trace}(M^TABM) = 
\operatorname{trace}(ABMM^T) = 
\operatorname{trace}(A)
$$

Comment: Please let me know if any of the steps I've taken or notation that I've used require clarification.

Comment: Why $M^TBM=I$ ?

Comment: $e_i^T X e_j$ is the $i,j$ entry of $X$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom.Thanks for answering to my guess.

Comment: You're welcome :)